# Length of an edge of the larger square base of a pyramid frustum, given slope of sides and length of the smaller base's edge

Tags: geometry

I'm working through a problem given in [Thompson's 1914 "Calculus Made Easy"](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283) (chapter 6, p 44 in the link) but my question is merely about the geometry/trigonometry aspect of the problem, not calculus. Hopefully I can capture and convey the aspect I am struggling with.

I will summarize:

- We have a frustum of a pyramid which is inverted (the larger base is on the top) (in this particular case, it is a reservoir of water)
- "The side of the bottom is 200 feet."
- "has sides sloping at an angle of 45◦ with the vertical"

He then goes on to say:

- " **It is easily seen that**, the slope being 45◦, if the depth be h, the length of the side of the square surface of the water [that is, the larger upper base] is **200 + 2h feet**" (emphasis mine).

I don't "easily see" this at all. I assume this means I'm lacking some key bit of intuition here. What am I missing?

Comment: Draw a diagram, and you will see what the author means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the side has a $45$ degree angle with the vertical, this forms an isosceles ($45$-$45$-$90$) right triangle, which means the horizontal leg on the top also has a length of $h$.  Since this widening happens on both sides, the side length of the large square is the side length of the small square plus $2h$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the side length at a depth of $h$ is $s$, then we can calculate the slope of the side as follows

$m = \tan 45^\circ = 1 = \dfrac{( \dfrac{s}{2} - 100 )}{ h }$

From this, it follows that

$ s = 2 h + 200 $